# OS X Calendar won't sync to iPhone

Tags: iphone, mac, data-synchronization, calendar

If I put an event in Calendar, on my Mac, in does not sync to my iPhone. However it does sync if I put an event into the iPhone when it will then pick up the previous unsynced events.

Comment: How are you syncing both devices?

Comment: It normally just does it, without a sync. But my phone is backed up to the Mac

Comment: It must have iCloud or other type of account activated to sync calendars. Please check on System Preferences > Internet accounts on your Mac and on Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars on your iPhone and add to your question the information that exists on both. My guess is you are adding events to a different calendar on your Mac, probably a local one. Then again, it may be a synced calendar but you have hidden it on your iPhone.

Comment: I checked and both were set also the pulling down of screen as below doesn't work. But as soon as I add some thing to my iPhone calendar it syncs

Comment: They were set how? Please be very specific.

Comment: On the Mac under system preferences>iCloud the calendar box is checked like wise on my iPhone settings>icloud> calendars is on

Comment: Is there more than one calendar on either?

Comment: No, just the usual family, work etc

Comment: So if I go to settings>iCloud then calendar is listed and ticked but if I then click on iCloud options, calendar is not listed as an app that store documents or data

Comment: If you go to the Calendar app on iOS, and tap on "Calendars" on the bottom of the screen, what do you see? Also, you mention you have "just the usual: family, work, etc."; **each** one of those is a **different calendar**, and they must be checked on both devices in order to be viewable.

Comment: There was a list of all the calendars:- All iCloud , work calender, Home etc at the top it says "show all calendars" if you click it all the clappers get ticked

Comment: Select them all on both your computer and iPhone and try again

Comment: Great it seems to be working now!!! Thank you very much for your help

Comment: Which version of MacOS (OS X) are you running?

Answer (score 1):

I have found that creating a "dummy" calendar event on my iPhone will unjam synching issues and force OS X and iOS systems to talk to each other. This is not a very elegant method, but it's effective. Simply delete the fake entry when your Mac and iPhone have shared their respective calendars.

Answer (score 1):

I tried the solutions and none worked for me; iPhone 5S sync with MacBook Pro High Sierra; I rebooted both devices; what worked was to go on iPhone Settings -> First icon (my name) then scroll down to iPhone(3) (the name of my iPhone - could be different for you) clicking on which solved the problem - at least for now.

Comment: Thank you. After spending 30m trying many solutions. This simple trick is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue recently as well.  One way that seems to force a resync is to first go to the list of Calendars at the bottom of the Calendar app.  Drag the list of calendars down, and the gear will start spinning at the top of the screen while the data is resynced.  This has worked for me so far.

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of iOS and OS X support many calendar service providers, and within them you may have different calendars for each category: Work, Personal, Family, etc.

Check on all synced devices that the same calendars are activated and visible.

On iOS, open the Calendar app, tap on Calendar, and select those you'd like to be visible.

On OS X, you can do the same on the sidebar.

Check the calendar (Work, Personal, etc.) of the event that won't sync.

Sometimes all it takes is to make the calendar viewable on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

This has been driving me crazy too. No matter what I tick in preferences, my iPhone calendar will not update/sync with my iMac. I don't want to use iCloud or bluetooth or whatever - I just want the iPhone to sync when I plug it into my iMac. The method (thanks KENT) outlined below is the only thing that has worked:

"I've had this issue recently as well. One way that seems to force a resync is to first go to the list of Calendars at the bottom of the Calendar app. Drag the list of calendars down, and the gear will start spinning at the top of the screen while the data is resynced. This has worked for me so far."